# VK Api [IFrame] передача данных в JS

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Есть чат на php данные пользователя в chat.php получаю так

```
 require_once 'chatfiles/vkapi.class.php'; #путь к файлу vkapi.class.php
    $api_id = 'ID'; #id приложения
    $secret_key = 'Key'; #секретный ключ приложения
$viewer_id = $_GET['viewer_id']; // id пользователя,не знаю откуда брать будешь   
$VK = new vkapi($api_id, $secret_key); 
$respo = $VK->api('getProfiles', array('uids'=>$viewer_id,'fields'=>'photo_50,first_name,last_name,sex'));   
$id    = $respo['response'][0]['uid'];
$fot   = $respo['response'][0]['photo_50']; // переменная с ссылкой
$name  = $respo['response'][0]['first_name'];
$fam   = $respo['response'][0]['last_name'];
$sex   = $respo['response'][0]['sex'];
$photo = "<img src='" . $fot . "'>";
```

Как можно данные параметры передать в JavaScript(отдельный подключаемый файл) чтобы использовать их в такой строке

```
 if(nrchats > 0 && objChat.chats[0].chat != '') {
      for(var i=0; i<nrchats; i++) {
        chatrows += '<p><span class="chatusr">&bull; '+ objChat.chats[i].user +' </span><em>'+ objChat.chats[i].date +'</em><span class="chat"> '+ bbcodeParser.bbcodeToHtml(objChat.chats[i].chat) +'</span></p>';
      }
```

Интересует именно вставка сюда **'+ objChat.chats[i].user +'**,пытаюсь вывести туда автарку юзера.

Answer (score 0):

Используй PHP прямо в HTML/JavaScript'е:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<!-- Это код PHP который Я сделал для доступа в API по ACCESS_TOKEN'у -->
<?php 
define('ACCESS_TOKEN', '********');

function api($method, $params = array())
{
    $params['access_token'] = ACCESS_TOKEN;

    $url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/' . $method . '?' . http_build_query($params);
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    return json_decode($response, true);
}
?>
<?php
 require_once 'chatfiles/vkapi.class.php'; #путь к файлу vkapi.class.php
    $api_id = 'ID'; #id приложения
    $secret_key = 'Key'; #секретный ключ приложения
$viewer_id = $_GET['viewer_id']; // id пользователя,не знаю откуда брать будешь   
$VK = new vkapi($api_id, $secret_key); 
$respo = $VK->api('getProfiles', array('uids'=>$viewer_id,'fields'=>'photo_50,first_name,last_name,sex'));   
$id    = $respo['response'][0]['uid'];
$fot   = $respo['response'][0]['photo_50']; // переменная с ссылкой
$name  = $respo['response'][0]['first_name'];
$fam   = $respo['response'][0]['last_name'];
$sex   = $respo['response'][0]['sex'];
$photo = "<img src='" . $fot . "'>";
?>
<p><span class="chatusr">&bull; <?=$photo?> </span></p>
<!--                        Вот ^^^^^^^^^^^ здесь.-->
</html>
```

Используя `код PHP который Я сделал для доступа в API по ACCESS_TOKEN` я получил такой вывод:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<p><span class="chatusr">&bull; <img src='https://pp.vk.me/c636716/v636716255/44a37/HOQtQsvpIwo.jpg'> </span></p>
</html>
```

PHP в JavaScript можно внедрить также как и в HTML:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
 if(nrchats > 0 && objChat.chats[0].chat != '') {
      for(var i=0; i<nrchats; i++) {
        chatrows += '<p><span class="chatusr">&bull;<?=$photo?></span><em>'+ objChat.chats[i].date +'</em><span class="chat"> '+ bbcodeParser.bbcodeToHtml(objChat.chats[i].chat) +'</span></p>';
        //                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
      }
</script>
```

Comment: все дело в том,что весь JavaScript - отдельный подключаемый файл,вот в чем беда)

Comment: Ну так почему бы не внедрить его? `<script type="application/javascript" src="external.js"></script>` в сам скрипт нужно внедрить PHP, а **перед** использованием скрипта задать переменные PHP.

Comment: То есть как-то так ?
`<?php
require_once 'chatfiles/vkapi.class.php'; #путь к файлу vkapi.class.php
    $api_id = '*'; #id приложения
    $secret_key = '*'; #секретный ключ приложения
$viewer_id = $_GET['viewer_id'];
$VK = new vkapi($api_id, $secret_key); 
$respo = $VK->api('getProfiles', array('uids'=>$viewer_id,'fields'=>'photo_50,first_name,last_name,sex'));   
$id    = $respo['response'][0]['uid'];
?>`
А потом строка
`<script type="text/javascript" src="chatfiles/chatfunctions.js"></script>`

Comment: @NasdomlanUrban3p Да, а в самом скрипте использовать PHP тэг `<?=$переменная?>`

Comment: спасибо,но из-за дурного кода боюсь так не выйдет)
Ибо сложно как-то структура чата сделана...
http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/script-chat-simple_s2
Данный чат использую,может подскажет что-то)

Comment: А может тогда сделать чтобы определенная функция(или несколько) получали переменную и выдавала ответ вместо того чтобы использовать PHP в коде внешенм JS, и после этого вызывать функцию JS в новом(внедренном) скрипте JS с использованием PHP переменных.
Сначала подключаем `chatfiles/chatfunctions.js`, потом допустим там есть функция `get_chat_info()` которая получает ссылку на изображение, а возвращает HTML тэг <img src="изображение">, используя ее следующим образом:
`<script type="application/javascript"> 
get_chat_info(<?=$fot?>);
</script> `

Comment: ,а вот это уже не понимает мой мозг)Я к сожалению слишком слаб в этой части)

Comment: Просто: 1. *Функция которая возвращает значение или выполняет действие по заданным параметрам.* 2. *Внешний вызов этой функции из внедренного JavaScript с параметрами из PHP тэга.* 3. *Получение результата или действия.* Рекомендую почитать: http://javascript.ru/basic/functions и обратить внимание на function sum(x,y), ведь именно такую функцию нужно делать, чтобы ее можно было вызывать из внедренного скрипта, после импорта внешнего(который  содержит данную функцию).